# Grails remoteLink not using my javascript

Tags: javascript, css, grails

I have this code in my gsp that i use when i create and edit

```
<div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: componentsInstance, field: 'inventoryItem', 'error')} required">
    <label for="inventoryItem">
        <g:message code="components.inventoryItem.label" default="Inventory Item" />
        <span class="required-indicator">*</span>
    </label>
    <g:select class="select2" style="width:30% !important" id="inventoryItem" name="inventoryItem.id" from="${rms.InventoryItem.list()}" optionKey="id" optionValue="name" required="" value="${componentsInstance?.inventoryItem?.id}"/>
</div>
```

It looks like this, ignore the quantity and unit fields[image]

It works fine on create but when i use remoteLink to edit somehow the javascript for my `class="select2"` doesnt work.

```
<g:remoteLink id="${ci.id}" controller="superAdmin" action="editComponents" update="componentsShown_${ci.id}">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" style="margin-right:5px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-remove"></span> Edit</button>
</g:remoteLink>
```

Now it looks like this
[image]

I use remoteLink to update my modal when i edit the body of my modal

```
<div id="componentsShown_${ci.id}">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <ol class="property-list">      
            <g:if test="${ci?.inventoryItem}">
                <li class="fieldcontain">
                    <span id="inventoryItem-label" class="property-label"><g:message code="components.inventoryItem.label" default="Inventory Item" /></span>               
                    <span class="property-value" aria-labelledby="inventoryItem-label">${ci?.inventoryItem?.name?.encodeAsHTML()}</span>                
                </li>
            </g:if>

            <g:if test="${ci?.quantity}">
                <li class="fieldcontain">
                    <span id="quantity-label" class="property-label"><g:message code="components.quantity.label" default="Quantity" /></span>
                    <span class="property-value" aria-labelledby="quantity-label"><g:fieldValue bean="${ci}" field="quantity"/></span>      
                </li>
            </g:if>

            <g:if test="${ci?.units}">
                <li class="fieldcontain">
                    <span id="units-label" class="property-label"><g:message code="components.units.label" default="Units" /></span>    
                    <span class="property-value" aria-labelledby="units-label"><g:fieldValue bean="${ci}" field="units"/></span>
                </li>
            </g:if> 
        </ol>                                                                   
    </div>

    <g:form>
        <g:hiddenField name="id" value="${ci.id}" />

        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" name="_action_deleteComponents" value="deleteComponents">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-remove"></span> Delete
            </button>                                               

            <g:remoteLink id="${ci.id}" controller="superAdmin" action="editComponents" update="componentsShown_${ci.id}">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" style="margin-right:5px;">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-remove"></span> Edit
                </button>
            </g:remoteLink> 
        </div>
    </g:form>
```

Comment: So, is your problem a style of select box? As I see, you use select2 plugin for that?

Comment: Is the issue with the `<g:remoteLink update="...">` part? The docs say  "... or a string with the element id to update", so I'd expect the entire  contents of `div#componentsShown_${ci.id}` to be replaced with the returned/rendered text of your controller (?).

Comment: @baxxabit yes  i think i may need to reinitialize my javascript because of the remotelink

Comment: @nickdos yes. the updated part looks like above

Comment: You need to re-initialize the `select2` JS after the AJAX content has been loaded. The `select2` plugin only modifies the select inputs on the original page loading, so it won't change your AJAX inserted DOM elements automatically - you need to tell it to explicitly.

Comment: @nickdos i did using the `onSuccess` attribute of `remoteLink`. it now works thanks